# asp.net MVC4 believes I'm in en-US not en-GB in windows 8 - how do I change this?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

```
    <meta name="accept-language" 
      content="@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name" />
```

... is returning en-US not en-GB which is then affecting my globalisation overrides for jQuery.

The only language/region I have installed is United Kingdom so I'm not sure where CurrentCulture.Name is being picked up from.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: Is the language/region set to the default of United Kingdom? What about the browser settings?

Comment: The call to `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name` is concern the server. Even if you are talking about the server, and you have login as account A, the pool is probably running by a different account, and the results are from that account.

Comment: @Kirk - bang on.  Chrome was using its own language settings rather than picking up from the OS

Answer (score 0):

Check web.config, globalization tag:

```
<globalization culture="any valid culture string"
               uiCulture="any valid culture string"/>
```

In your case the value should be:

```
<globalization culture="en-GB"
               uiCulture="en-GB"/>
```

Comment: Hi KPL - I believe this would force the application to run as en-GB rather than adapt to the user's local setting?

Answer (score 0):

Kirk was right - Google Chrome has its own language settings instead of picking up from the underlying OS.